# How do I access a locked Hotmail account?

Tags: outlook.com

I am not in my home country and I just wanted to access my Hotmail. It’s locked as it is asking for phone verification which is not possible for me. My previous phone number was of my home country and now I am in different country. How should be regain access to my account?

[image]